# How to call a method that requires "self" in Python?

Tags: python, api

I am very new to python and am trying to figure out what needs to be passed to this method. I'm sure this is such a noob question, but how do I create an object to pass to self?

```
class Bittrex(object):

    def get_markets(self):

        return self._api_query(path_dict={
            API_V1_1: '/public/getmarkets',
            API_V2_0: '/pub/Markets/GetMarkets'
        }, protection=PROTECTION_PUB)

    get_markets(self) //My attempt to call
```

Comment: Instantiate `Bittrex` and then call `.get_markets()` on it.

Comment: I found [this](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/) really helpful when I was learning about classes in Python.

Comment: See akash karothiya's answer

Answer (score 2):

Create an object of class `Bittrex` and then call method using `.`

```
b = Bittrex()
res = b.get_markets()
```